# Strictly positive part

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I'm having trouble with the definition of strictly positive part from "Basic Proof Theory" by Troelstra. For instance is the formula

$$\exists x (B\lor C) $$

s.p.p? What about $(A\implies B\lor C )$? And finally what about the last formula with an existensial quantifier?

Comment: Page 5 : "*(i)* [a formula] $A$ is a positive and strictly positive subformula of itself".

Comment: By *(iii)* $(B \lor C)$ is a strictly positive part of $∃x(B∨C)$ and by *(ii)* so are $B$ and $C$..